# MySQLInstallerConsole not setting root password?

Tags: mysql

I am installing MySQL on Windows with the following command line:

```
MySQLInstallerConsole community install -silent server;5.7.12;x64:*:type=config;servertype=Server;openfirewall=true;generallog=true;serverid=3306;enable_tcpip=true;port=3306;rootpasswd=%1;installdir="C:\MySQL\MySQLServer-5.7":type=user;username=foo;password=bar;role=DBManager
```

This line is contained in a script, and I pass in the root password from a random generated string. However, I am getting an access denied for 'root'@'localhost' when trying to access the server via

```
mysql -u root -p
```

(and providing the password)

I can not find any issues with the parameters for MySQLInstallerConsole. Connecting as user foo even works, but I really need the root password to work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using special characters in password parameter? "%1" could be expandig with wrong characters

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I can rule this out - the generator uses a-z A-Z 0-9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured out what the issue was: the system had a MySQL server installed before. The service and binaries had all been removed, but there still was a MySQL data directory in the default location (somewhere in %ProgramData%"). This seems to cause to make the installer console fail to finish the new installation WITH a different root password.

Removing the old data directory and re-running the installer command line as stated in the original question (without any changes) resulted in successful installation.